# How to get timestamp from string date with timezone, PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to create ics start and end time (UTC) with format like:

```
DTSTART:20141107T110000Z
DTEND:20141107T120000Z
```

I have following Object as input:

```
"event": {
    "timezone": "GMT+2",
    "start_time": "2014-11-07 13:00:00", // client local time
    "duration": 30
     },

 function _calc_end_date($start, $duration) {
    $start_date = new DateTime($start, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $end_date = $start_date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$duration.'M'));
    $end_date_str = $end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    return $end_date_str;
 }

 private function dateToCal($timestamp) {
    return GMDATE("Ymd\THis\Z", $timestamp);
}

 $timezone  = $event['timezone']; // ????       
 $start = strtotime($event['start_time'] . " UTC");
 $end_date = $this->_calc_end_date($event['start_time'], $event['duration']);
 $end = strtotime($end_date . " UTC");
```

So I write:

```
"DTSTART:" . $this->dateToCal( $start ) . $eol .
"DTEND:" . $this->dateToCal( $end ) . $eol .
```

This code works but I get result with 2 hours difference. As you can notice I don't entered TimeZone because I don't know how.

```
$timezone  = $event['timezone']; //
```

Somehow I need parse  "GMT+2" and calculate

```
$start = strtotime($event['start_time'] . " UTC");
```

with TZ.

Please help,

Comment: if you are using UTC why do you need a timezone? UTC is the same all over the world

Comment: Client iOS sends his local time + his TZ to let me calculate UTC properly.

Comment: so you have the UTC and you want to calculate the local time?

Comment: I need convert his local time + TZ to UTC format (timestamp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s O", $event['start_time'] . ' ' . $event['timezone'] );
$date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( 'GMT' ) );
$startDate = $date->format( "Ymd\THis\Z" );

$date->add( new DateInterval( 'PT' . $event['duration'] . 'M' ) );
$endDate = $date->format( "Ymd\THis\Z" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring and indexof to grab everything after the "+" and add that number of hours to the time

Answer (score 0):

What is source timezone name? This code works for me:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime("2014-11-07 13:00:00 Europe/Warsaw"));
```